# How to generate random convex polyhedral with constrained edge length

Tags: matlab, random, geometry

I want to randomly generate a convex polyhedral, but with the following conditions:

1. All vertices and edges lie within the cubic with corners (0.0, 0.0, 0.0) and (1.0, 1.0, 1.0).
2. Let ***L*** be the length of a edge, it should satisfy ***Lmin <= L <= Lmax*** for every edge. (for example, ***0.4 <= L <= 0.6***)

I have tried the following Matlab code:

```
figure();
vetices = rand(50,3);
k = convhulln(vetices);
trisurf(k, vetices(:,1), vetices(:,2), vetices(:,3));
```

Then I get something like this:

[image: example]

But this doesn't meet requirement 2, that some edges are too short and some edges are too long. I want to make the edge length distribution more concentrated.

Thanks for any advice or code. (code in Matlab, c++ or python is OK)

Comment: *code in Matlab, c++ or python is ok*. Choose 1

Comment: @AnderBiguri  If I must specify one language, then it will be Matlab. And a two dimensional solution is also OK, I will try to extend it to 3D.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach in 2D: Start with a regular polygon with the right edge length. Then iterate over the vertices and change it carefully so that your requirements are still fullfilled. Since every vertex has only two neighbours it's easy to ensure that the new polygon is still convex.